# Facebook social Login issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I have a Social login for my flutter app like Google and Facebook. I want to check the condition if user has already login and again want to login through other Social login then inside Firebase no need to create another account details for this user simply login it with the previous user details.
inside firebase i have Users node having all the user data are there.

```
This below function is for facebook login

  Future<void> signInWithFacebookAndLink(
      BuildContext context, DatabaseService dbService, String medium) async {
    // Check internet connection
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      // No internet connection
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          content: Text('No internet connection!'),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }
    try {
      // Step 1: Sign in with Facebook
      final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

      if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
        final AccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken!;
        final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
            FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);

        // Step 2: Authenticate with Firebase
        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);

        print('testing 1');

        // Inform the user about successful sign-in
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            content: Text('Successfully signed in with Facebook!'),
          ),
        );
        // Navigate to HomeScreen
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
          ),
        );
      } else if (result.status == LoginStatus.cancelled) {
        // Handle canceled login
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            content: Text('Facebook login canceled.'),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // Handle other login errors
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            content: Text('Facebook login failed.'),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is FirebaseAuthException &&
          e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
        print('testing 2');

        // If there's an error because the account already exists with another sign-in method:

        // Step 3: Prompt the user to decide if they want to link accounts
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Account Exists'),
              content: Text(
                  'An account associated with this email address already exists with another sign-in method. Do you want to link the accounts?'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close dialog
                  },
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close dialog
                    // Step 4: If the user agrees, link the Facebook account to the existing account
                    final LoginResult result =
                        await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
                    if (result.status == LoginStatus.success) {
                      final AccessToken? accessToken = result.accessToken;
                      if (accessToken != null) {
                        final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
                            FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token);
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
                            ?.linkWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
                        print('testing 3');
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            content: Text(
                                'Successfully linked Facebook to your account!'),
                          ),
                        );
                        // Navigate to HomeScreen
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
                          ),
                        );
                        print('testing 4');
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Link'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        // Handle other errors here
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            content: Text('An error occurred: $e'),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Suggestion: Please add error message

Comment: Have you implemented necessary API token requirements in the info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml files?